# Hibernate insert using session.persist seems not possible (POJOs generated by netbeans)

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, hql, pojo

I'm making a database-first hibernate api.

I let netbeans generate the POJO's and mapping files from the database. (Using "Hibernate Mapping files and POJO's from database")

The foreign keys in the database are now references to POJOs.

For example:
Class A has foreign key relation with Class B, then class A POJO is:

```
Class A {
    private B b;
    private Integer idA;

    public A (B b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    //const, getter, setter

}
```

If I want to create a new A-object and insert it into the database (using Hibernate.session.persist(a)) , I run into problems.

It seems I also have to create a B-object (but this B-object has a foreign key to table C and so on)

So should I, instead of using the session.persist, write a hql query to insert a new A-object

```
Query q = session.createQuery(INSERT INTO A (idB) 2);
q.executeUpdate(q);
```

(or does using hql queries have disadvantages over using the session.persist(a)?)

Or should I manualy edit the POJO's and mapping files to contain table B id's, in stead of class B objects?

Or is there something I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance, if I need to provide any additional information, let me know
greetings

Comment: What is the complete stack trace of the exception you get when persisting A?

Comment: @JB Nizet, I don't get a stacktrace since I cannot type the code to create a new instance of A (it requires a B-instance, which in turn needs a C-instance, and so on)

Comment: `new A(null)` allows creating an A without a B. What's the problem? And it's your code. You're allowed to add a constructor which doesn't need a B if you want one.

Comment: If there is no stacktrace, how do you know the line Hibernate.session.persist(a) is the problem? The JVM must have send some kind of messages. 
Be sure that B is not a required mapping column...